# jQuery Form Remote Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

there i was cracking my head finding the error i had make in my jQuery remote validation. I had try to search in the google for any solution and i had try all but no luck it still got error. It alway return false although the sno is not exist in the database. Please help me on this.Thanks

Here is my form.js example code:

```
jQuery("#form1").validate({
        rules: {   
            industry: "required",
            sno: {
                required:true,
                remote: "check-sno.php"
            },
messages: {
            sno: {
                required:"Please Enter Source Number",
                remote: "S.No is already taken."
            },
```

Here is my check-sno.php code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','csci311');

if (!empty($_POST['sno']))
{
    $sno = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['sno']);
    $query = "SELECT sno FROM prospects WHERE sno = '{$sno}'";
    $results = $mysqli->query($query);
    if($results->num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo "true";  
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false"; 
    }
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

is there any query mistake i had made? Please correct me,thanks :)

FYI, the remote function in the form.js. It alway prompt the remote message whether or not i typing the existing sno or not existing sno.

Did i need to return any value after the validation?

Comment: Use prepare method. Here you've incorrect sql statement. It should be -  `SELECT sno FROM prospects WHERE sno = $sno`

Comment: @AVD i had change the query, but it still prompt the error message that it was taken although it was not exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated element and its value **as a GET parameter**. The response is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string...

By default, the `remote` method is using the **GET** method, however, your PHP is looking for the **POST** variable, `$_POST`...

```
if (!empty($_POST['sno'])) ....
```

Since there is no `$_POST` variable when `remote` is using GET, it's always `empty`, so then you're always echoing `false` and triggering the validation message.

Simply add the `type` option to your `remote` rule to change the default method from `GET` into `POST`...

```
sno: {
    required:true,
    remote: {
        url: "check-sno.php",
        type: "post"   // <- use the POST method
    }
},
```

BTW- The `remote` rule/method will accept all of the same options as [jQuery `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

**EDIT**:

If your PHP is broken, you will also get nothing but the validation message.  As per docs, a `false`, `undefined` or `null` response all trigger the validation error.  In other words, you'll have to do some troubleshooting to independently verify that your PHP is functioning properly.

Comment: i had changed the method you suggest. But no luck it alway prompt the messages " S.No is already exit"

Comment: @Marcus, it's working fine for me.  You know that if your PHP is broken, the `remote` will also show the validation message.  You have to verify that your PHP is working properly.  What troubleshooting have you performed to that end?